# Generate random string in c

Tags: c, arrays, string

In this code I'm generate random number in specific range, but I want the out put of array must be

```
m1,m1,m3,m1 ..
```

I mean adding the word "host" to every number that is generate randomly, how can do this please? 
this is code

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int a[50];

  srand(time(NULL));

      a[i] = rand() % (3 + 1 - 1) + 1 ;
      printf( " %d\n", a[i]);

}
```

Comment: well, check out `snprintf()`.

Comment: printf( "host%d\n", a[i]);

Comment: _'Here I am printing a number. How do I print something else next to the number.'_ Really? Did you try... just putting that other thing in the `printf()`? And who is upvoting this, and why?

Answer (score 3):

In your code, `a`is an integer array, so it cannot hold a *string value anyway*.

- In case, you just want to *only* print the value, use `host` in the format string in `printf()` itself, like

  ```
   printf( "No. of random selected node = host%d\n", a[i]);
  ```
- In case, you want the value to be generated and *used*, in some way, take a buffer and use [`snprint()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) to populate the content.

  ```
   snprint(buf, 8, "host%d", a[i]);
  ```

  the above will put values like `host101`, `host103` etc. in the `buf`, as a *string*. Remember, `buf` has to be large enough to hold the supplied size (`8`, in this case.)

  *Note: Never use magic numbers like `8` in above code, that's just for illustration, use a MACRO definition, at least*.

Comment: Code that does not check the return value from `snprintf()` is not "more" safe" than simply using `sprint(buf, "host%d", a[i]);`. `snprintf()` is trading one problem (buffer overrun) for another (mal-formed string).